# GC issue with QuickFIX/J

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finance, quickfixj

We are creating a low-latency Java application with QuickFIX/J . We are subscribing to around 50 currency pairs so we are getting around 4000000 ticks per day. This is because we are getting them from different liquidity providers.

I am seeing lots of GC happening and at peak time our application is hanging and not responding.  I have tried with with 64 GB heap and also tried with G1 for GC but no success. Can you please suggest how I can solve this issue?

Did you face this issue earlier and what GC optimization have you done?

Should I move from QuickFIX/J and try with some other FIX engine? Can you please suggest some open source/commercial FIX engine which can fulfill my requirement?

Presently I am using Java 7.  Would moving to Java 8 be helpful?

Comment: Ok QuickixJ isn't designed for throughput you are dealing with. It is better you customize QuickfixJ or tinker with your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you have a 8 hr working day you get 138 ticks/second per average. I'm well aware that it is the extremes that count but this is all we got.
138 ticks/seconds should not be a problem at all. We get that x100 every day with a 2 GB heap without a problem. 
Chances are, you have a memory leak. Do you have gc logging going?
If you do not, install it immediately.

These are the flags we use:

-Xloggc:/gc-$(date +"%0d-%0m-%y-%0k%M").gclog
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCCause

GC logging has very small performance impact.
If you post the gc log once you got it, we can take it further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i would enable GC logs and would post

Comment: http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=L2hvbWUvcmFtL3VwbG9hZC9pbnN0YW5jZTEvc2hhcmVkLzIwMTYtNS0yNi9nY2xvZy5nY2xvZy0xNC0zMi0yMg==

Comment: this is my report but for shortter duration . I would post for complete day run

Comment: 7 minutes is a bit short :-), the problem is not manifesting itself. I think a longer run is needed. Also, when running CMS, ParNewGC is default so you don't need that. I notice you are adjusting plab size, have you noticed any performance benefits from that?

Comment: I would publish my GC logs today for a complete one day. I didn't change plab size.

Comment: No? I was thinking of this  -XX:OldPLABSize=16

Comment: http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=L2hvbWUvcmFtL3VwbG9hZC9pbnN0YW5jZTEvc2hhcmVkLzIwMTYtNS0yNy9nY2xvZy5nY2xvZy0xMi0zMS0xMA==

Comment: This is report for 9 hour which i think is not that bad

Comment: And did you get a freeze this time around? The gc log looks perfectly normal. You probably draw down on the memory allocation considerably. This will make full gc faster as the time for traversing the heap will be faster.

Comment: How i can down memory allocation .is there any vm argument which i can use for this

Comment: Um, the flag '-XX:MaxHeapSize=...' sets the max heap size?

Comment: Hi. Today i run this with raw data and i can see very bad result .29 Major GC in less then a hour.http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=L2hvbWUvcmFtL3VwbG9hZC9pbnN0YW5jZTEvc2hhcmVkLzIwMTYtNi05L2djbG9nLmdjbG9nLTEwLTE1LTE0